# Como redireccionar a un controlador laravel utilizando Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

quisiera hacer algo como esto desde Vuejs:

en una funcion cualquiera por ejemplo:

```
method: {
     guardad(){
       toastr.success('guardado');
       progressBar: true,
       return redirect()->action('UsuarioController@index');
     }
}
```

como veran he cruzado codigo vue con laravel, pero es porque no se como hacer el redireccionamiento desde vuejs, he colocado la url completa, pero al hacerlo me tira la pagina en blanco, por ejemplo localhost:8000/usuarios me imagino que es porque en mi web.php tengo un resource('usuario',UsuarioController) y el se encarga del direccionamiento.

Comment: No seria mucha molestia que subas una demostración visual como un video para ver los resultados. Para ver exactamente cual es el resultado:

Comment: Como subo un video? o tengo que abrir otro tema  @AndrusDiaz

Answer (score 0):

**Para solucionar tu problema (Sí es realizar llamadas a los controladores sin cambiar de ruta)** debes comunicar Laravel con Vuejs lo normal es : [Crear una Api en Laravel](https://medium.com/@david.quezada.m/tutorial-api-restful-con-laravel-5-6-en-menos-de-1000-palabras-e14249fef9a9) y [consumirla/llamarla en Vuejs (En este caso utilizaremos Axios)](https://www.groloop.com/vue-js-2-7-consumir-una-api-la-libreria-axios-crear-filtros-personalizados/).

La respuesta de como realizar esto es un poco larga por esta razón deje los enlaces para que puedas aclarar tus dudas. 
Si seguimos el primer tutorial y creamos la ruta localhost:8000/api/usuarios en Laravel con la librería llamada Axios especificada anteriormente. Quedaría algo muy parecido a lo que quieres.

```
 guardad(){
       toastr.success('guardado');
       axios.get('https://localhost:8000/api/usuarios').then(resp => {
          console.log(resp) // Esto es la respuesta de la peticion
       })
     }
```

**Para solucionar tu problema (Si es abrir rutas de controladores existentes cambiando de ruta)** puedes utilizar una redirección en JavaScript:

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin +'/ejemplo'
```

Esto su tu App en Vuejs está alojada en Laravel, la llamada sería **localhost:tupuerto/ejemplo** llamando al controlador que colocastes en esa ruta.

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080' +'/ejemplo'
```

Si tu App en laravel está en otro localizacion reemplazas **http://localhost:8080** por tu dominio y ejemplo es la ruta de tu controlador igualmente

Comment: Fijate que con axios ya habia probado y me tira el mismo resultado, una pagina en blanco. y la solucion que me diste con javascript me da el mismo resultado, si me tira la ruta que es, pero no me aparece nada y si yo le doy enter en la ruta, si me tira mi formulario.